# JacORB: client side development

Tags: corba, jacorb

I am reading about JacORB in context of CORBA. There are many terminologies involved...idl, idl compiler, client, servant, server, ORB, stub, skeleton, IIOP, naming service etc.

My objective is to implement client side of the overall system. I have IDL files with me, and I can generate related java files from them.

I am following [this](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://www.jacorb.org/releases/3.9/ProgrammingGuide.pdf) resource on JacORB.

But I am not very clear how to move ahead.

I am not sure on several things, like how do we actually find remote objects, connect to them to invoke methods, configure naming service on client side, or how to configure remote server(host, port etc) on client side. I understand that some server side artifacts, like servant, server etc are also created, but are they needed on client side too?

Comment: Far too broad to answer here. You need to read a good CORBA tutorial.